# Sort list of class objects in c#

Tags: c#, list, class, sorting, object

I want to sort list of class objects.

```
class tocka
{
Point t;
double kut;
int redkotiranja;

public tocka(Point _t, double _kut, int _redkotiranja)
{
t = _t;
kut = _kut;
redkotiranja = _redkotiranja;
}
}
```

Here is the list:

```
List<tocka> tocke= new List<tocka>();
tocka a = new tocka(new Point(0, 1), 10, 1);
tocke.Add(a);
tocka b = new tocka(new Point(5, 1), 10, 1);
tocke.Add(b);
tocka c = new tocka(new Point(2, 1), 10, 1);
tocke.Add(c);
tocka d = new tocka(new Point(1, 1), 10, 1);
tocke.Add(d);
tocka ee = new tocka(new Point(9, 1), 10, 1);
tocke.Add(ee);
```

I want to sort list `tocke` by `t.X`

How I do that in C#?

Answer (score 3):

Using LINQ:

```
tocke = tocke.OrderBy(x=> x.t.X).ToList();
```

Make `t` public.

Answer (score 1):

Direct solution without LINQ (just list sorting, no additional list creation).

Providing that `t` is made public:

```
  tocke.Sort((left, right) => left.t.X - right.t.X);
```

But the best way, IMHO, is to make `class tocka` *comparable*:

```
class tocka: IComparable<tocka> {
  ...

  public int Compare(tocka other) {
    if (Object.RefrenceEquals(other, this))
      return 0;
    else if (Object.RefrenceEquals(other, null))
      return 1;

    return t.X - other.t.X; // <- Matthew Watson's idea
  }
}

// So you can sort the list by Sort:

tocke.Sort();
```

Comment: +1 for providing an answer that doesn't copy the list into another collection, sort it, then copy it back into another list - thus avoiding a bad case of LINQitis. ;) BTW I think you can simplify the comparison by just returning `(other.t.X - t.X)` since the value only needs to be +ve, -ve or 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ, for instance like this:

```
tocke.Sort( (x,y) => x.t.X.CompareTo(y.t.X) );
```

but first you have to make `t` public, at least when getting it:

```
public Point t { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

- First of all you should add the `public` modifier to your class.
- Second you should refactor your fields to properties. It is suggested to expose properties to the public than fields.

Then the solution would be as follwos

```
public class Tocka
{
    public Point Point { get; private set; }
}
```

As answer to your question you shall use `Linq`

```
List<Tocka> l = ...
var orderedTocka = l.OrderBy(i => i.Point.X);
```

Note: Just be sure that Point is never `null`, otherwise the `Linq-Query` listed above won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can sort in-place using:

```
tocke.Sort((a, b) => a.t.X.CompareTo(b.t.X));
```

Or using LINQ (creates a new list):

```
tocke = tocke.OrderBy(x=> x.t.X).ToList();
```

You should probably encapsulate `t` as a property. Also, if `t` can be `null`, you should add nullity checks to the above lambdas.